# Fixing an A HREF tag inside Datatables' column filtering dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using Bootstrap X-Editable for inline-editing a CRUD. I happened to be using it in conjunction with Datatables and it works like a charm, until I am required to add a filtering option on one column that has an x-editable dropdown.

Basically, the table is this:

```
<table class="table-striped table-condensed" id="sortable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Src_id</th>
<th>Element_name</th>
<th>Src_type_id</th>
<th class="select-filter">Subcontract_id</th>
<th class="select-filter">Language_id</th>
<th class="select-filter">Site_id</th>
<th class="select-filter">Costcentre_id</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
@foreach($elements as $key => $value)
 <tr>
        <td width="10px"><input type="checkbox" name="ids_to_edit[]" value="{{$value->src_id}}" /></td>
            <td>{{ $value->src_id }}</td>
            <td><a href="#" class="testEdit" data-type="text" data-column="element_name" data-url="{{route('elements/update', ['src_type_id'=>$value->src_type_id, 'src_id'=>$value->src_id])}}" data-pk="{{$value->src_id}}" data-title="change" data-name="element_name">{{$value->element_name}}</a></td>
            <td>{{ $value->src_type_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value->subcontract }}</td>
            <td><a href="#" class='testEdit2' data-column="language_id" data-url="{{route('elements/update', ['src_type_id'=>$value->src_type_id, 'src_id'=>$value->src_id])}}" data-pk="{{$value->src_id}}" data-title="change" data-name="language_id">{{ $value->language }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ $value->site }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value->costcentre }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

and the initialization on the Language ID column is this:

```
$('.testEdit2').editable({
    type: 'select',
    source: [
    <?php foreach($languages as $key => $value){ ?>
        {value: <?php echo $value->language_id; ?>, text: '<?php echo $value->language; ?>'},
    <?php } ?>
    ],
    params: function(params) {
        // add additional params from data-attributes of trigger element
        params.name = $(this).editable().data('name');
        return params;
    },
    error: function(response, newValue) {
        if(response.status === 500) {
            return 'Server error. Check entered data.';
        } else {
            return response.responseText;
            // return "Error.";
        }
    }
 });
```

Unfortunately, Datatables' column filter shows it like this:

[image]

and I've found that it pretty much included the entire href tag along with it:

[image]

I'm wondering how I can possibly clean this initialization up to remove the `<a href></a>` tag.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sortable').DataTable({
      "stateSave": false,
      initComplete: function () {
              this.api().columns('.select-filter').every( function () {
                  var column = this;
                  var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                      .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                      .on( 'change', function () {
                          var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                              $(this).val()
                          );

                          column
                              .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                              .draw();
                      } );

                  column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                      select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                  } );
              } );
          }
  });
} );
```

Comment: So it looks like there's some problem with the PHP that outputs the table?  Can that not be fixed?

Comment: sorry..No, there's no problem with PHP, x-editable and any server side thingamajigs..the problem is removing how to filter the a href tag inside the column filter of Datatables (see screenshots).. It basically produces an output of Empty">Empty, etc. because of the href tag I used inside the Language ID cell